# Elasticsearch date histogram aggregation includes more than one bucket per month

Tags: elasticsearch, statistics

I am trying to create a Elasticsearch date histogram aggregation using monthly intervals.  For some reason, the month of November ends up getting two buckets - one for the start and end of month.  The following is a screenshot from the Kibana Data Table visualization:

[image]

This is essentially doubling the metric values for the month of November which is bad news for reporting.  I couldn't find anything in the docs relating to this issue...  Any ideas as to why the aggregation is including two buckets for the month of November?

Comment: You might be victim of a [Daylight Saving Time bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8339) (since last year it was on October 26th in some countries and November 2nd in some other countries). Which versions of Elasticsearch and Kibana are you running?

Comment: I'm running Elasticsearch 1.5.2 and Kibana 4.0.2.

Comment: Ok, then you're most certainly victim of [Kibana issue #3694](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3694), which is still open and slated to be fixed in 4.1.1 and 4.2.0